# Configure SOLR indexing with AEM 6.1

Tags: solr, aem

I am trying to configure SOLR indexing with AEM 6.1 but struggling with the following: -

1. What type of installation should be used for SOLR (embedded v/s
   remote).
2. How to configure the selected installation with AEM 6.1.
3. How to determine whether the indexing has been successfully done.

Any help would be extremely appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

I did lot of research on SOLR with AEM 6.0.  I think I can answer to your question.

1. It depends on what are the requirements of the client.  If the clients needs a quick search response and it have lot of content, you should prefer remove vs embedded.  If the site has small content, the embedded could be sufficient.  The remote permit to have a sharded cluster, so you can optimize the concurrent search response by adding more shared
2. The documentation of AEM is pretty well documented about this.  You can find here: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/platform/queries-and-indexing.html
3. Finally you can see the indexation well configured by enabling the logging configuration about the search (Look for to Enable Logging in the previous URL).  You can test your search with tool in the ACS-Common with tools in ACS-Tools (http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/)

Hope this will help you.
Stéphane

Comment: They say's that embedded should be only used for "develop purpose" not for "production" environment.. i think you MUST always use remote..

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon these projects, as I searched for AEM Solr integration:

- https://github.com/headwirecom/aem-solr-search
- https://github.com/infielddesign/aem-id-solrindexer

Maybe it will help you with the Solr integration and configuration.
And as already mentioned above, the type of installation highly depends on your customer requirements.